# Merge method in Hartl's Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Just a simple question, I'm assuming it has a simple answer from Hartl's Chapter 4.6 Exercise #4. Not sure what the value should be? 
Is it `true` or `false`? Thank for any clarification.

Find an online version of the Ruby API and read about the Hash method merge. What is the value of the following expression?

```
  { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }.merge({ "b" => 300 })
```

Comment: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try it in [irb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) or in a Ruby script:

```
{ "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }.merge({ "b" => 300 })
# => {"a"=>100, "b"=>300}
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

> `hash.merge(other_hash)` returns a new hash containing the contents of other_hash and the
>   contents of hash. If no block is specified, the value for entries with
>   duplicate keys will be that of other_hash. Otherwise the value for
>   each duplicate key is determined by calling the block with the key,
>   its value in hash and its value in other_hash.

So, to answer your question precisely, `merge` does not return boolean values (`true` or `false`), it returns a ***new hash***.

Comment: Ah ok I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you understand the concept :)